# Installing ubuntu without DE but only Zoom video conference app?

Tags: system-installation

Is this even possible to install a bare minimum system and have ONLY Zoom video conference application on it? i.e. without a desktop environment? I have an old but usable netbook that I would like to devote to this experiment.

Comment: No: Zoom depends upon functions provided by the desktop. It's like trying to ride a bicycle without the frame.

Comment: I don't know anything about `zoom` so it's likely @user535733 is 100% correct, but you maybe able to use a WM instead  (rather than a DE, but I'd bet a lot of the DE toolkit/libraries would be installed & needed, even if the DE itself isn't running).  This maybe the best you can do, but as I don't know zoom & don't see it in the repositories, I can only express my *uneducated* opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to run Zoom without a desktop environment, but obviously, you need more than a text console. The application will expect a graphical stack to run on, so you need xorg or wayland. The application will expect to connect to audio and webcam, so you need that set up as well.

That might actually be relatively easy when the software is packaged as a `.deb` installer, because then, the APT system automatically can pull in all required dependencies.

Having a lightweight desktop environment installed still will make life easier, against only a very small extra overhead.